# How to convert JSON to resultset in JAVA?

Tags: json, jdbc, resultset

I am trying to tweek jdbc driver to read data from json source instead of database without changing functionality of application program. For this, I need to convert JSON to java resultset. There are several ways of converting resultset to json and that takes care of insert/update statements. But for select statement, I need to convert Json to resultset. Any ideas or help is appreciated.

Comment: It isn't at all clear what this has to do with PostgreSQL. You seem to want a JDBC driver that stores JSON "instead of database" - do you mean in flat files? If so, start by reading the JDBC specification, write a simple driver.

Comment: I am trying to cache results of postgres as json objects in ehcache. So in case of cache hit, I am able to retrive data which is Json format. But not able to convert this json into resultset which is required by application.

Comment: OK, so you *are* talking to the DB, and you want to make the cache transparent to the app so it *appears* to still come from the DB. You're attempting to add transparent client-side caching to PgJDBC. Er. Good luck with that - cache invalidation problems will drive you insane.

Comment: @CraigRinger: We figured that out. I think we are not facing that issue as of now on the data we tested. Just this final piece of code with which we can convert json to resultset can help us make a good cache. Please help me out, if you are able to think of any way in which we can possibly do this.

Answer (score 1):

We figured out a work around. Now storing the resultset in webRowSet(implementation of cachedRowSet) in order to serialize/deserialize it.